# What's the cleanest way to remove Homestead and Vagrant from a Windows system?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, composer-php, windows-10

I followed the instructions in [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead) to install Vagrant and Homestead on Windows 10, but now I've decided to move the whole development stuff to another dedicated server running Debian.

I need to fully remove Vagrant, Homestead, Composer as well as AMPPS (old stuff) from the Windows 10 desktop. It should be easy to simply uninstall Vagrant and AMPPS, but how do I go about cleaning up the remaining things?

I don't need to keep any of the code etc. I've already got that in a different location.

Comment: Just delete it. Homestead is just files within your directory.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**Virtual Machine**

Remove the homestead VM by running

```
vagrant box remove laravel/homestead
```

---

**Homestead**

If you installed Homestead via composer with the following command:

```
composer global require laravel/homestead
```

run the opposite to remove it:

```
composer remove laravel/homestead
```

This will remove the .composer/vendor/laravel directory, including its 'homestead' subdirectory. The 'global' keyword is not required.

On a Mac or Linux system, the Homestead configuration files can be removed by deleting the '~/.homestead' directory. You may need to hunt a little to find the directory on your Windows system. Don't worry too much if you can't find it; the directory is small and innocuous.

---

**Composer**

Composer is usually installed as a Windows application; check Add/Remove programs (or the Windows 10 equivalent) to uninstall it.

If you installed Composer manually and it does not appear in your list of installed apps, simply remove the 'composer' binary and the configuration directory (~/.composer on Mac/Linux systems).

Comment: The `composer remove laravel/homestead` command gave me this error: 

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                    
  Could not read ./composer.json                                                        
  file_get_contents(./composer.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
```

Comment: @kevnk I had the same problem. At first you need to 'cd' into the folder where you composer.phar are located then I resolved it with adding "sudo". So it now looks like this "sudo composer remove laravel/homestead" maybe this can help other people as well.

Comment: If you have composer installed globally try `composer global remove laravel/homestead` else follow feri advice.

Comment: For removing virtual machines I did `vagrant box remove laravel/homestead --all` since I had several versions of laravel/homestead boxes. You can find the boxes with `vagrant box list`

Answer (score 35):

Step 1: Get a list of all installed boxes using

```
$ vagrant box list
```

Step 2: Run vagrant remove command, specify the box name, version, and provider for example

```
$ vagrant box remove laravel/homestead --box-version=0.4.4 --provider=virtualbox
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, a way to remove a specific version of the same box.

Comment: Looks like I'm back again to reference the same thing, thanks twice!

Comment: Yes, Me to, this is exactly what I was looking.

Answer (score 1):

Run the command `vagrant box remove laravel/homestead --provider=virtualbox --all`
to avoid having to specify a version if multiple are on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

For me on Windows 10, after removing the one box and uninstalling Vagrant, it was not until I went into Virtual Box (which I used before Vagrant) and deleted the appliance, where I regained my hard drive space.  I got back 6GB alone with this deletion.