# Troubles with Homestead / Laravel installation (Mac)

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, homestead

I was following these instructions to install homestead on my Mac
http://pastebin.com/48PHSNC2

Homestead installed properly, but when it initialized, it didn't create a Homestead.yaml file. I have no idea how to reinitialize homestead or fix this. Reading through the installation guide Laravel gives you, it suggests using `$ bash init.sh` to create the .yaml file... unfortunately, this apparently doesn't exist for me either.

I used the composer command to install the CLI:

`composer global require "laravel/homestead=~2.0"`

Any ideas? I'm stumped...

Comment: I also tried doing the `homestead init` command again, it just says that homestead has already been initiated and won't let me do anything.

Comment: Now run `homestead edit` to configure your sites and then run `homestead up` to start the homestead.

Comment: @pespantelis I have no Homestead.yaml file. I cannot use any commands homestead offers. 

"The file /Users/admin/.homestead/Homestead.yaml does not exist."

Comment: I guess it's about permission issue. However, I have not to suggest something.. :\

Comment: @pespantelis Is there any possible way to re-initialize homestead? i.e uninstalling laravel/homestead through composer and then re-installing it?

Comment: This maybe help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067192/whats-the-cleanest-way-to-remove-homestead-and-vagrant-from-a-windows-system

Comment: Solved. Found out my pathing to my homestead file was incorrect. Changed the pathing, found the init.sh hidden in the depths of the void. Ran `bash init.sh`, initiallized homestead and voila! the Homstead.yaml was created.

Comment: Create an answer explaining your solution and accept it. Perhaps someone with similar issues can be helped in the future.

Comment: ya i'm stuck on this! More clarification please

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue using Homestead 2.X (I dont care for Homestead 3 ATM).

basically do the following:

- find the bash_init.sh file by running `sudo find / -name init.sh`
- cd into the directory it's in, mine was in `/Users/me/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead/init.sh`
- make it executable, by running `chmod +x init.sh`
- run `./init.sh`
- ...
- profit!

Answer (score 0):

You can generate manually by clone `git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead`. This will generate homestead.yaml file. Open and edit and change the parameters to fit your system configuration. For further reading

https://dev.to/ko31/installing-laravel-homestead-on-macos-5910